# scooter won't start at all

Tags: scooter

I have a 50cc fly scooter2008 I changed the choke, gas,  plug  I get spark fuel to the carb but not the plug, when I block the air intake I can get it to run only while I keep my hand

Comment: Disassemble and clean the carb.